# Reset dropdown by selecting a disabled option as default in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to clear some dependent dropdowns controlled by react state. Everything works okay as long as the default option is not set to disabled.

Taking this fiddle, which is part of another stackoverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57491948/1031583)  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-epsdsz

If you change the `<option>Select</option>` by `<option disabled>Select</option>` the "clear" button will stop working and will go to the first selectable option.

Is there any way in react to reset a select by going back to the disabled option? or I must leave the "Please Select" as selectable and then run a validation for those specific fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use `option` values and it will work as expected. This way, when you set the selected state to an empty string, React renders the disabled option as selected:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
      selected: '',
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selected: e.target.value });
  };

  handleClear = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selected: '' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.selected}
          name="Auditee"
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        >
          <option value="" disabled>
            Select
          </option>
          {this.state.data.map((data) => (
            <option value={data}>{data}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.handleClear}
        >
          Clear
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following what I'm thinking you're asking for, managing disabled in the state should work. When Clear is clicked, update the state so that the first option is enabled again, then when any other option is picked, you can set disabled for the first option back to true.

Edit: You should set selected back to "Selected", not "". I'm not sure why I thought that the first time. The behavior is still the same with the fix.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      data: ["one", "two", "three"],
      selected: "",
      firstDisabled: false
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ selected: e.target.value, firstDisabled: true });
  };

  handleClear = e => {
    this.setState({ selected: "Selected", firstDisabled: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />

        <select
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.selected}
          name="Auditee"
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        >
          <option disabled={this.state.firstDisabled}>Select</option>
          {this.state.data.map(data => (
            <option>{data}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.handleClear}
        >
          Clear
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```